# Tracking traffic from a third party app

Tags: web, google-analytics, web-traffic

I work for a company which is essentially a jobs board. We have partnered with an organization and they have agreed to post our job feed on their app. How do I track the traffic coming from this app to my website? Please advise. The jobs are posted as an iframe. Do I need to use UTM tags to identify the traffic? If yes, the URLs are dynamic as of now so how do I implement the tags?

Comment: ..seems you're quantum female.. So is either chic (0) or girl (1)... you can't have it both! Anyway... enlighten us wiht what you tried so for yourself... now your question its too broad what you're asking.

Comment: i am both chic & a girl...so that's chicgirl for you :) So i have a jobs feed embedded in an ios app. We have partnered with these guys and a section of their app hosts our jobs. How can i track the traffic my website is receiving from this app?

Comment: no no..quantum.. you're running an info while loop now. I meant... have you got access to their code to implement yours... kinda crucial.. ID tag and jobID tag.. not sure why you want to share your data for free with this weird 10^googol company..

Comment: From what i know from my tech team, the partner site grabs our RSS jobs feed into their app...Is that helpful? Is this the right approach? Please guide

Answer (score 0):

Per job you generate an URL link.

With your RSS-feed you implement an URL... in that URL you should have the UTM tag included and analytics installed on your website.

See [here](https://funnel.io/resources/google-analytics-utm-tagging-best-practices) where that is explained in great detail. Also, check the tutorials from G analytics itself in detail.

> For example, on website A there is a link to website B: http://www.websiteb.com/. Provided that website B has Google Analytics installed, visits from website A will show up in Google Analytics as
>
> Source = http://www.websitea.com 
>   Medium = referral

... the essentials explain here:

> The tracking standard used by Google Analytics is called UTM parameters. Because Google Analytics is the de facto standard for website analytics, the same applies to UTM parameters. You have probably noticed these at some point in the browser URL field after clicking a link. A typical URL in an ad could look something like this:
>
> http://www.website.com/?utm_source=newssite.com&utm_medium=cpc&utm_campaign=my-campaign
>
> Everything after the “?” in the URL above is information for Google Analytics to correctly categorize visits from this link to the website.

Comment: So UTM tagging is the only way to identify traffic coming from a partner's app to my website. I was thinking right. Thanks for the information. Appreciate your inputs.

Comment: Keep in mind...there are among us who use Neat URL to get rid of the tracking garbage to prevent this search-engine company from collecting too much info from us. That's why I'd asked if you you can implement your own referral... then you are in control and not these scrapers.

Comment: Yes we can implement it thankfully. Thanks for the suggestion.